# Proper way of passing array parameters to D functions

Tags: arrays, d

1st Question:

Are D array function parameters always passed by reference, or by value?
Also, does the language implements Copy on Write for arrays?
E.g.:

```
void foo(int[] arr)
{
    // is arr a local copy or a ref to an external array?

    arr[0] = 42; // How about now?
}
```

2nd Question:

Suppose I have a large array that will be passed to function `foo` as a read-only parameter and it should be avoided as much as possible copying the array, since it is assumed to be a very large object. Which from the following (or none of them) would be the best declaration for function `foo`:

```
void foo(const int[] bigArray)

void foo(in int[] bigArray)

void foo(const ref int[] bigArray)
```

Comment: in your list in is a no-op (dunno where it makes any sense), further, istead of using const use immutable whereever appropriate because it is stronger than const'ness

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Technically, a *dynamic array* like `int[]` is just a pointer and a length.  Only the pointer and length get copied onto the stack, not the array contents.  An `arr[0] = 42;` does modify the original array.
   On the other side, a *static array* like `int[30]` is a plain old data type consisting of 30 consecutive `int`s in memory.  So, a function like `void foo(int[30] arr)` would copy 120 bytes onto the stack for a start.  In such a case, `arr[0] = 42;` modifies the local copy of the array.
2. According to the above, each of the ways you listed avoids copying the array contents.  So, whether you need the parameter to be `const`, `in`, `const ref` or otherwise depends on what you are trying to achieve besides avoiding array copy.  For example, if you pass a `ref int [] arr` parameter, not only you can modify its contents, but also you will be able to modify the pointer and length (for example, create a wholly new array and assign it to `arr` so that it is visible from outside the function).

For further information, please refer to the corresponding articles on the DLang site covering [arrays](http://dlang.org/arrays.html) and [array slices](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html).